# Is a uncountable set infinite?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Would being uncountable imply infinity? We know that if a set is countable it could be either be infinite or finite, what about uncountable sets?

Comment: Yes, uncountable sets are infinite.  Personally, I'd never say that a finite set was "countable".  Not sure if there's a universally accepted convention on that.

Comment: Yes a finite set is countable, hence a uncountable set cannot be finite.

Comment: Uncountable is often taken as synonym for uncountable infinite, hence it is infinite

Comment: @zebullon: the are no finite uncountable sets !

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by infinite? -- bounded or unbounded?

Comment: @JustKevin: That's an odd question.

Comment: uncountable sets can be bounded or unbounded.  i believe that was the isomorphism from countable sets to uncountable sets.

Comment: @YvesDaoust . euh yep sure ?.... Don't see how your statement is opposite to mine though. Often in measure theory, "countable" is taken to be either finite or countable infinite, for ex the rationals (so infinite), and "uncountable" is a shortcut for uncountable infinite, for ex the reals (infinite)

Comment: @zebullon: you don't qualify uncountable as infinite, this is a pleonasm.

Comment: * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set: "Some authors use countable set to mean countably infinite alone".

* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set:  "an uncountable set (or uncountably infinite set) is an infinite set "

I think @Xenidia has now enough materials to accept an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the definition you use. Some definitions call a set $M$ countable if there is a bijective map $\varphi : \mathbb{N} \to M$. In this case finite sets would not be considered countable. Others call a set countable if it is in bijection to some subset of $\mathbb{N}$, in this case finite sets are countable. However the term uncountable almost always includes that the set is infinite. So depending on your definition you either have

1. Countable sets.
2. Uncountable sets.

or

1. Finite sets.
2. Countable sets.
3. Uncountable sets.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be an uncountable set. Note that if $E$ is finite, then by definition there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{1, \dots, n \}$ is in bijection with $E$, so $E$ is countable. But this is a contradiction.

Comment: As @Bemte pointed out, there are several definitions out there. For clarity, you should include which one you used in the proof, this might not be obvious on first glance.

Comment: @Luke, Being obvious or not depends. There are always people here talking like a grader; though I am not sure if such a person likes people who ain't a grader talking to them in such a tone, I believe no one likes.

Comment: Re-reading this, my comment sounded rather cocky indeed. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, uncountable sets have a greater cardinallity than any countable, as countable includes one infinite set, it must by default be infinite too.